# Code requires API level 11 (current is 8)

Tags: android, version

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("log", s);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

This code gives the error "Code requires API level 11 (current is 8)". Only because these 3 lines I need to change minSdkVersion from 8 to 11. Is it possible to have minSdkVersion 8, and do something with this code - for example, execute it only if current version is at least 11? But I still want to have this functionality, and don't want to change minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your code into a conditional block to make it run only on platform versions that allow it:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("log", s);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Also you may want to tell `Lint` to use a warning level on this case instead of the normal error level that it uses:

`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking -> Select New Api and change the severity to Warning`

Comment: he shouldn't set it to be a warning. if he handled the "error" , he can add an annotation that means "ok lint , i've taken care of it, trust me..." . just click the quick-fix and choose how you wish to tell lint that you've handled this problem.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Finally I added @SuppressLint("NewApi") before the function with this code instead of changing the preferences.